# Is similarity defined for proper classes?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Wikipedia's page on [Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) provides a definition for similarity over metric spaces.  I was wondering if there was an accepted definition for similarity which extends to proper classes, not just metric spaces.

For context, I'm playing with some philosophical ideas and the idea of something being similar to "everything" showed up.  I'm curious if saying "This set X is similar to the class of all sets" has an accepted formal meaning for mathematicians.

Comment: What is the shape of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depending on what you even mean to begin with, this seems that you want something like a "shape preserving bijection" (e.g. shifting or uniform stretching), given that the class is some subclass of a proper-class structure that can make sense of these terms.

In that case, yes, we can talk about two proper classes being similar. Just like we can talk about two proper classes being isomorphic as partial orders. We just have to postulate the existence of a proper class which is a bijection preserving whatever structure that you want it to preserve.

Of course, the real issue here is that postulating the existence of a proper class is done in the meta-theory, so your statement "these two classes are similar/isomorphic/best friends/whatever" is now taking place in the meta-theory, rather than inside the set theoretic universe.

Comment: That is very helpful.  Thanks.  If I may paraphrase (to see if I understand), it's reasonable to talk of similarity between classes based on the structure of those two classes, but what is actually meant by that can only be described in the meta-theory used to define the classes?

Comment: Yes, pretty much that. You can talk about things which are provable, for example, ZF proves that every proper class of ordinals is order isomorphic to $\rm Ord$. But the proof is an algorithm that lets you transform the definition of your class into a definition of an isomorphism. So it's a meta-theorem, or as I like to call them, "proof schema/proof templates". This is different from ZF proving that every set of ordinals is isomorphic to an ordinal, though, even though the proof is "practically the same".